# create resource (cronjob) boilerplate with `kubectl`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm on my way to learn k8s, and I'd love to know how we can create boilerplate for **cronjob**.

I know it used to be follwoing.

`kubectl run mycron --schedule "1 * * * *" --image nginx -o yaml --dry-run`.

Even it still outputs the boilerplate but it says following.

> kubectl run --generator=cronjob/v1beta1 is DEPRECATED and will be
>   removed in a future version. Use kubectl create instead.

However I couldn't find how to generate it with `kubectl create`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks it's no more possible to create the scaffolding directly from the CLI:

```
# kubectl create
(...)
Available Commands:
  clusterrole         Create a ClusterRole.
  clusterrolebinding  Create a ClusterRoleBinding for a particular ClusterRole
  configmap           Create a configmap from a local file, directory or literal value
  deployment          Create a deployment with the specified name.
  job                 Create a job with the specified name.
  namespace           Create a namespace with the specified name
  poddisruptionbudget Create a pod disruption budget with the specified name.
  priorityclass       Create a priorityclass with the specified name.
  quota               Create a quota with the specified name.
  role                Create a role with single rule.
  rolebinding         Create a RoleBinding for a particular Role or ClusterRole
  secret              Create a secret using specified subcommand
  service             Create a service using specified subcommand.
  serviceaccount      Create a service account with the specified name
```

As you can see, no `cronjobs` command available: from my experience, I would suggest you to checkout [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#cronjob-v2alpha1-batch) according to your Kubernetes running version and fill a temporary YAML and then proceed with a `kubectl create -f path/to/file.yaml`